# Training New AutoTokenizer Hugging Face

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

> Getting this error: AttributeError: 'GPT2Tokenizer' object has no
> attribute 'train_new_from_iterator'

Very similar to hugging face documentation. I changed the input and that's it (shouldn't affect it). It worked once. Came back to it 2 hrs later and it doesn't... nothing was changed NOTHING. Documentation states train_new_from_iterator only works with 'fast' tokenizers and that AutoTokenizer is supposed to pick a 'fast' tokenizer by default. My best guess is, it is having some trouble with this. I also tried downgrading transformers and reinstalling to no success. df is just one column of text.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import tokenizers

def batch_iterator(batch_size=10, size=5000):
    for i in range(100): #2264
        query = f"select note_text from cmx_uat.note where id > {i * size} limit 50;"
        df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=cmx_uat)

        for x in range(0, size, batch_size):
            yield list(df['note_text'].loc[0:5000])[x:x + batch_size]

old_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta')
training_corpus = batch_iterator()
new_tokenizer = old_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, 32000)
```

Comment: what did you think about the answer? did it help with the problem?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669365/huggingface-bert-tokenizer-add-new-token/76198096#76198096

Answer (score 2):

There are two things for keeping in mind:

**First**: The `train_new_from_iterator` works with fast tokenizers only.
([here you can read more](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/15077))

**Second**: The training corpus. Should be
a generator of batches of texts, for instance, a list of lists of
texts if you have everything in memory. ([official documents](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer))

```
def batch_iterator(batch_size=3, size=8):
        df = pd.DataFrame({"note_text": ['fghijk', 'wxyz']})
        for x in range(0, size, batch_size):
            yield df['note_text'].to_list()

old_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
training_corpus = batch_iterator()
new_tokenizer = old_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, 32000)
print(old_tokenizer( ['fghijk', 'wxyz']))
print(new_tokenizer( ['fghijk', 'wxyz']))
```

output:

```
{'input_ids': [[0, 506, 4147, 18474, 2], [0, 605, 32027, 329, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}
{'input_ids': [[0, 22, 2], [0, 21, 2]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]}
```